# How to filter the data containing array inside the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, filtering

```
const arrayList = [{
  fNo: 343,
  origin: "Singapore",
  destination: "India",
  upType: ["Eco to PEco", "Eco to HClass"]
}, . {
  fNo: 363,
  origin: "Chennai",
  destination: "Singapore"
  upType: ["PEco to HClass"]
}]

const fiteredRulesData =
  arrayList.filter((data: any) => data.fNo.toString().includes(fNo.toString()))
```

&& ...similarly for other data like origin and deatination && how to do it for the upType array)

other is working but upType is not.
Getting values fNo, origin and destination from the input but on selecting data getting upType as filterUpType = ["Eco to PEco"]

Comment: can the array have more than one element?

Answer (score -1):

```
const filteredItems = arrayList.filter(item => item.upType && Array.isArray(item.upType) && item.upType.indexOf("Eco to PEco") !== -1)
```

Comment: in other upType array which we getting from selecting value is upType= ["Eco to PEco", etc] we need to check index of that uptype also , cant directly put the string into indexOf ,how can i do that